# Github Action -> "Error: Forbidden: Invalid credentials or this AWS S3 bucket name may already be taken"

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, action, serverless

**Issue Summary**
I'm "Error: Forbidden: Invalid credentials or this AWS S3 bucket name may already be taken" even new bucketName is provides in serverless.yaml.

**Expected behavior**
Type of deployments: dev, staging, production
I'm looking solution for multiple type of deployment of NextJS SSR project via GitHub Action.
There are buckets for each deployment: let say MyBucketDev, MyBucketStaging, MyBucketProduction
Let say git action script has section for each type of deployment and respected branch is pushed, it will automatically does CI/CD bu running "serverless deployment" to the respected buckets.
cloudfront urls should not change for each deployment. If bucketName is configured correctly, i guest it should not be problem.

**OS/Environment:**
@sls-next/serverless-component version:
Next.js version: 14 or 15
Additional context
Please, can you help me?
a) How can i avoid issue/problem in above?
b) Am i doing right steps as explained in Expected behavior section?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> There are buckets for each deployment: let say MyBucketDev, MyBucketStaging, MyBucketProduction

Bucket names [must](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucketnamingrules.html) be only **lower-case**. Also they [must](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingBucket.html) be **globally unique**.

Your error msg suggests that whatever names you are using are already used by someone else. Make sure that they are unique by adding some random suffix, e.g.:

```
my-bucket-dev-32154asdf, my-bucket-stageing-32154asdf, my-bucket-production-32154asdf
```